# Having trouble echoing different data using the function method

Tags: php, function, echo

I'm writing a PHP file which will putt from multiple table rows, data which it must echo on one page.

I wrote a function command because I a loop wont work as the information isn't outputting in the same manner every time.

here is how it looks so far.

```
include("dbconnect.php");
function get_table_data($id)
{
    $row = mysql_query('SELECT row FROM table WHERE id = '.$id.'');
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($row);
};
$sss = 18; // this is the ID
echo get_table_data($sss);
```

My issue is that nothing echos and I have no errors

Comment: warning! your code is vulnerable to sql injection!

Comment: You're blindly executing a select query with a value that you are injecting via PHP. Should you pass a value into the function get_table_data that you retrieve from a form on a web-site, voila you are injected.

Comment: Your function does not return anything. Apart from that - you cannot echo an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you need to return something:

```
function get_table_data($id) {
    $row = mysql_query('SELECT row FROM table WHERE id = '.$id.'');
    return mysql_fetch_array($row);
}
```

then, you need to access the row:

```
$result = get_table_data($sss);
echo $result['row'];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that helps. Does this prevent SQL injection?

Comment: Not if you get the ID with `$_GET` or `$_POST`. In this case you should check with `is_numeric()` if the `$id` is a number.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `get_table_data` should return some value to be echoed in your statement `echo get_table_data($sss);`